# Computing $\mathscr O_X (X − \{x\})$ for $X$ an affine scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, affine-schemes, ringed-spaces

Let $R=\Bbb Z[T], X = Spec\ R, \mathfrak m := (T − 2, 3)$ where $\mathfrak m$ is a maximal ideal of $R$.

Compute $\mathscr O_X (X − \{x\})$ where $x\in X$ corresponds to $\mathfrak m$.

We have $X − \{x\}=D(T-2) \cup D(3)$ where $D(f)$ are the affine open 
 of X corresponding to $f\in R$.

Hence  $\mathscr O_X (X − \{x\})=\mathscr O_X (D(T-2)) \cup \mathscr O_X (D(3)) $ which is equal to the set of elements of $\Bbb Q(T)$ of the form $\frac{P}{(T-2)^i}, i\in \Bbb N, P\in \Bbb Z[T]$ or of the form $\frac{P}{(3)^i}, i\in \Bbb N, P\in \Bbb Z[T]$.

But looking at the hint, $\mathscr O_X (X − \{x\})=\Bbb Z[T]$.

I don't understand, thank you for your help.

Comment: $\mathscr O_X (X − \{x\})=\mathscr O_X (D(T-2)) \cup \mathscr O_X (D(3)) $ is not true, I think you need to take an intersection $\cap$.

Comment: If I take the intersection, then that works indeed as $T-2$ and $3$ are not associated in $\Bbb Z[T]$. But why the intersection? is is linked to the fact that $\mathscr O_X$ is a sheaf and therefore we have to impose a glueability condition on the sections?

Comment: Intuitively you can think that a function which is regular on $U\cup V$ has to be regular on both $U$ and $V$, so the regular functions on $U\cup V$ are the intersection of the regular functions on $U$ and the regular functions on $V$.

Comment: Nice intuitive explanation, thank you!